# MediaPlayer in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player

I'm trying to make an array of MediaPlayers but get a TargetInvocationException when trying to run the following code. Why doesn't it work?

works:

```
MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer00 = new MediaPlayer();

MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer01 = new MediaPlayer();

_mediaPlayer00.Open("...");

_mediaPlayer01.Open("...");
```

dont work:

```
MediaPlayer[] _mediaPlayers= new MediaPlayer[2];

_mediaPlayers[0].Open("...");

_mediaPlayer[1].Open("...");
```

another question. Is it possible to use only one mediaplayer for multiple sounds? if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is because each `MediaPlayer` element in the `MediaPlayer[]` array is `null` when first initialized, so you must initialize the elements first.

```
_mediaPlayers[0] = new MediaPlayer();
_mediaPlayers[1] = new MediaPlayer();

_mediaPlayers[0].Open("...");
```

OR

```
foreach(MediaPlayer p in _mediaPlayers)
p = new MediaPlayer();
```